# ListView hide or collapse selected group

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, .net-3.5, show-hide

How can I hide or collapse some group in `ListView`?

I just add some items

```
contactListView.Items.Add(new ISIMlistViewItem(contact));
if (contact.availability == 6)
    contactListView.Items[contact.identificator].Group = contactListView.Groups["offlineGroup"];
else
    contactListView.Items[contact.identificator].Group = contactListView.Groups["onlineGroup"];
```

And I want to sometimes hide the `offlineGroup`.

```
if (hideOffline == true)
{
    // something like
    contactListView.Groups["offlineGroup"].Hide();
    // or
    contactListView.Groups["offlineGroup"].Visible = false;
}
```

But I don't know how can I do that. Can I just collapse it and don't draw it or is there any possibility to hide it?

Comment: http://typecastexception.com/post/2012/05/09/Extending-C-Listview-with-Collapsible-Groups-%28Part-I%29.aspx

Answer (score 6):

It seems that the .NET version of the [`ListViewGroup` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewgroup.aspx) does not provide a `Collapse` or `Expand` method.

Luckily, the native `ListView` control does support it and one guy provided [an extension to enable expand and collapse](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31276/Add-Group-Collapse-Behavior-on-a-Listview-Control).

Using his code you can then have a function to set the expand/collapse state with:

```
private void SetGroupCollapse(GroupState state)
```

For hiding a complete group I would simply remove all the items in this group.

Comment: I've the same idea. But I though that I can simply hide any group I want and also simply show it again. I don't like move items from one group to some temp place to hide group and then back to show group. I think that I'll use collapse extension.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the source code of control derived from ListView which has Collapsable logic properly implemented:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36775/Collapsible-ListViewGroup

Using this control, and after creating the items and groups I had to call:

```
lvIssues.SetGroupState(ListViewGroupState.Collapsible);
```

And my groups turned nicely into collapsable.